# Thymeleaf custom dialect with fragments: how to keep th: attributes

Tags: thymeleaf

I'm creating a custom dialect that replaces `<myprefix:mytag>` with a `<div th:replace="myTagFragment::myfrag">` and it works with no attributes or "standard" attributes.

It stops working if I use `th:` attributes in the custom tag.

This works:

```
<myprefix:mytag required id="myid">
```

This does not work:

```
<myprefix:mytag th:field="*{name}">
```

TagProcessor code snippet:

```
protected void doProcess(ITemplateContext context, IModel model, IElementModelStructureHandler structureHandler) {

final IOpenElementTag customTag = (IOpenElementTag) model.get(0);
//
// I create a comma-separated list of the original attributes and add them in the fragment with th:attr
Map<String, String> attributes = sourceTag.getAttributeMap();
String attributeString = attributes.toString(); // "{attr1=val1, attr2=val2}"
attributeString = StringUtils.chop(attributeString); // Remove "}"
attributeString = StringUtils.removeStart(attributeString, "{"); // Remove "{"
structureHandler.setLocalVariable("attributeString", attributeString); // "attr1=val1, attr2=val2"
//
Map<String, String> newtagAttributes = new HashMap<>();
newtagAttributes.put("th:replace", "myTagFragment::myfrag");
IOpenElementTag replacementTag = modelFactory.createOpenElementTag("div", newtagAttributes, AttributeValueQuotes.DOUBLE, false);
model.replace(0, replacementTag);
```

Fragment snippet from "myTagFragment.html":

```
<th:block th:fragment="myfrag">
    <div>somestuffhere</div>
    <input th:attr="__${attributeString}__">
```

When I use

```
<myprefix:mytag type="password" maxlength="70" id="titolo">
```

I correctly get the replaced fragment:

```
<div>somestuffhere</div>
<input type="password" maxlength="70" id="titolo">
```

but if I want to use `th:` attributes in the original tag, they fail because something like
`th:field` is not processed properly when added with `th:attr="__${attributeString}__"` of course.

Maybe there is a way to retrieve the fragment model from inside the TagProcessor and add the th: attributes by code?
Any other idea to replace a custom tag with a template fragment while keeping the original attributes and have them processed when needed?

Answer (score 0):

The (partial) solution I found so far is to process `th:` attributes myself in the TagProcessor: most of them just need to be replaced with the equivalent plain version after evaluation, some others need a special trearment, some more I just ignore.

(pseudo)Code snippet:

```
Map<String, String> attributes = sourceTag.getAttributeMap();
Map<String, String> targetAttributes = new HashMap<>();
for (Map.Entry<String,String> sourceAttribute : attributes.entrySet()) {
    String attributeName = sourceAttribute.getKey();
    String attributeValue = sourceAttribute.getValue();
    if (attributeName.startsWith("th:") && !attributeName.endsWith("append")) {
      String thAttributeName = ... remove "th:" from the name
      String parsedValue = null;
      if (!"attr".equals(thAttributeName)) {
        try {
          final IStandardExpression expression = parser.parseExpression(context, attributeValue);
          parsedValue = (String) expression.execute(context);
        } catch (Exception e) {
          log.debug("Can't parse \"{}\" for tag \"{}\" - skipping", attributeValue, attributeName);
          continue; // Next attribute
        }
        switch (thAttributeName) {
          case "field":
              targetAttributes.put("name", parsedValue);
              targetAttributes.put("value", parsedValue);
              break;
          ... also handle "attr", "alt-title", "lang-xmllang"
          default:
              targetAttributes.put(thAttributeName, parsedValue);
    } else {
        // Plain attributes with no "th:"
        targetAttributes.put(attributeName, attributeValue);
    }
}
... repeat the loop to handle "append" and "prepend" attributes here
String attributeString = targetAttributes.toString();
... same cose as in the question follows
```

The problem with this approach is that all conditional and looping th tags are lost, so I can't use th:each on my custom tag for example.

Comment: Also `th:oninput="somejs()"` usually works but converted to `th:attr="oninput=somejs()"` does not work because it needs quotes: `th:attr="oninput='somejs()'"`

Comment: so I need to quote all values: `targetAttributes.put(attributeName, "'" + attributeValue + "'");`

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to give a higher precedence to my custom dialect so that all th: attributes are executed before my tag processor.
This way I can use `th:each` and other stuff on my custom tag (see discussion [here](https://github.com/thymeleaf/thymeleaf/issues/805)).

The only problem seems to be with `th:field` because it checks the tag before adding name/value attributes and skips them on any custom tag.

```
public class YadaDialect extends AbstractProcessorDialect {
    public YadaDialect() {
        super("Yada Dialect", "yada", StandardDialect.PROCESSOR_PRECEDENCE+1);
    }
```